# In Microsoft Word 2007, is there a way to put in a variable which can be set and altered?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to make a document in which I can add a specific date at the top (for example, 03 October 2014). This date would be the main variable from which six other dates would align themselves to.

That is, the date at the top would be the "Week Ending" date on a Friday for an employee's timesheet. Further down the document, I would want a field which would reduce this date value to 29 September 2014. Then a table followed by another value of 30 September 2014, etc.

So by setting the main variable at the top to 03 October 2014, I would want the other dates on the document to automatically adjust. This would be easy on Excel, but I cannot find a simple way to do this on Word. Can you advise?